# Bash script not navigating to folder, only accepting input when "exit" is typed manually

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have the following bash script I am trying to use so I can speed up updates to my code. For some reason it gets stuck at `cd /var/www/myapp/code` and only prompts input when I type `exit` to return to the root user.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pulls from remote repo and implements changes

su - rails
cd /var/www/myapp/code
git pull
expect "sername for 'https://bitbucket.org':"
send "myusername"
interact
expect "assword for 'https://username@bitbucket.org':"
send "mypassword"
interact
exit
cd /var/www/myapp/code
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
nginx -t && sudo nginx -s reload
```

I tried manually entering `cd /var/www/myapp/code` but it's still not executing until I type `exit`.

Comment: In general - try to find where your script is getting stuck by running your script with `-x` ([more info here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)). Also, in case of a simple script you can verify its functionality by simply executing the commands manually. BTW I think your usage of `expect` and commands related to it (`send`, `interact`) is incorrect - you might want to check out some tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit of re-factoring, but a solution is to wrap everything in a single su - (user) -c "bla" call, which will automatically exit the subshell as (user) once the commands are all done.

Syntax:

> su - (user) -c "command"

Here's how I'd do it:

Note that we have to break commands up with ';', and escape double-quotes with a '\'.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pulls from remote repo and implements changes

su - rails -c "cd /var/www/myapp/code; 
  git pull;
  expect \"sername for 'https://bitbucket.org':\";
  send \"myusername\";
  interact;
  expect \"assword for 'https://bitbucket.org':\";
  send \"mypassword\";
  interact" # Now that the final command's ran,
            # we'll auto - exit the subshell

cd /var/www/myapp/code
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
nginx -t && sudo nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. After running `/$HOME/bin/quickup.sh` I get this: `-bash: //root/bin/quickup.sh: Permission denied` My bash script is in quickup.sh

Comment: Are you running this as root?

Comment: Yes, It's kind of strange. Am I even supposed to use `expect`, `send`, and `interact` when dealing with a username/password prompt?

Comment: You certainly can. I'm curious as to how you're getting a permission denied. Can you try pasting the su - rails -c command into your CLI and see if it works? This is the only change that was made.

Comment: I get `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address` followed by `command not found` for the rest. After I manually enter `git pull` I get this prompt: `Username for 'https://bitbucket.org':` so It should be a match.

Comment: Well, this is due to a configuration setting on your account, did you make sure to change "myusername" and "mypassword" to the values that were globally configured @ bitbucket? If you get lost here, there are plenty of stack overflow posts related to this "no such device or address" error.

Comment: Yes, I used the correct username and password for my account and my pull requests work when I do it manually.